# Improving loop speed (apply doesn't help)

Tags: r

I need to speed a simulation I am conducting, and I have found that a particular component of one of my functions is the main culprit for how slow it is.

The job of this part of the function is to demonstrate how increasing the number (*n*) of random draws from a distribution increases the precision of the mean estimate of that set of draws.

The procedure is as follows:

- Sample *n* random draws from a normal distribution with fixed parameters *mu* and *sigma*, where *n* varies from 1 to 500. (In this example, I just set mu = 500 and sigma = 100.)
- At each *n*, calculate the mean of all sampled values
- Repeat this procedure 1,000 times.

I currently have this in a nested loop, which I know is not efficient. Here is the code:

```
# generate empty container for the simulated data
# parameters: 
# n_repetition = how many times to repeat the whole procedure
# max_n = maximum number of draws to explore

set.seed(42)
n_repetition <- 1000
max_n <- 500

# function to generate n random draws, and find their mean
r_norm <- function(n, mean, sd){
 temp <- rnorm(n, mean, sd)
 return(mean(temp))
}

sim_results <- matrix(0, nrow = n_repetition, ncol = max_n)

for(i in 1:n_repetition){
 for(j in 1:max_n){
   sim_results[i, j] <- r_norm(j, mean = 500, sd = 100)
 }
}
```

This is pretty slow; about 9.80 seconds on my machine. I therefore tried to use an "apply-family" approach. This turns out to be just as slow:

```
sim_results <- matrix(1:max_n, nrow = max_n, ncol = n_repetition)
sim_results <- apply(sim_results, 1:2, r_norm, mean = 500, sd = 100)
```

I am not sure how to proceed. I thought the slow-down in R would be the looping, but I removed this using "apply" and it was just as slow.

I cannot even think how to make this faster, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Apply is still looping, it's just hiding the loops so you don't have to write it yourself. It's a very simple procedure you are doing - there's not a lot to be done to speed it up. You could call `.Internal(mean())` directly instead of `mean()` to shave off a few microseconds of dispatch and input checking, but completing 500k simulations in less than 10 seconds doesn't seem too bad. Why do you need this to be faster? Are you re-simulating this frequently? Do you need every single `j` in there? Easy way to get a 10x speedup would be to run `j` as `seq(10, max_n, by = 10)` instead of `1:max_n`

Comment: Thanks @Gregor. Unfortunately I do need every j in there. I've tried to simplify the idea behind my full simulation to focus on the issue. The above procedure is likely to be repeated 1000 times for **each** set of parameter values passed to the sampled distribution (64 parameter variations). This means the full simulation will take about a week.

Comment: Instead of generating 500 different sets of random numbers per repetition.  Try generating one set of 500 numbers and using the `cummean` function on the list.  Then generate a new set for the next repetition.

Comment: Your `apply` doesn't do the same thing than your loop, you translated your matrix and you don't use `mean` in `apply` so each cell value is a vector. You probably want `apply(sim_results, 1:2, function(x) mean(rnorm(x), mean = 500, sd = 100))`

Comment: Is this you actual simulation? Normal distribution, with the parameters you are varying as the mean and sd? You can get a theroretical result fairly easily. And you can do it for mean 0 and sd 1 and add/multiply to get the results for other means and variances.

Comment: @JulienNavarre Error from translating my real example to a simpler one. Now corrected to call a function "r_norm". In the real simulation, I am calling from a more involved distribution.

Comment: @Gregor No, this is toy example. I am sampling from an ex-Gaussian distribution in my full simulation.

Comment: I'd encourage you to look into whether it's the random draws or the means that are the bottleneck. My guess is taking the means is at least an order of magnitude faster than the random drawing from your distribution, meaning that the only way to get a substantial speed up is to reduce the number of draws (or improve the speed of the draws). Dave2e's suggestion, to do a single draw of 500 points and use `cummean` on it is a very good one, if you would satisfied with that method.

Comment: @Dave2e This is excellent, thank you very much; this will certainly suffice! I cannot seem to accept an answer. Do I not have enough reputation?

Comment: @Gregor.  Thank you for the vote of confidence, answer posted below.

Comment: If the full simulation is more involved you could get an additional speedup by running repetitions or different parameter settings in parallel (e.g., with `mcapply` or `foreach`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my comment above.  The existing nested for loop is generating an new set of random numbers for each repetition.  An improvement is to generate 1 set of random numbers per repetition and use the built-in `cummean` function.

The code below shows the comparison between the original code and the improvement.  The original code took about 13 sec, the improvement ~1 sec.

```
print(Sys.time())
set.seed(42)
n_repetition <- 1000
max_n <- 500

sim_results <- matrix(0, nrow = n_repetition, ncol = max_n)

for(i in 1:n_repetition){
  for(j in 1:max_n){
    sim_results[i, j] <- mean(rnorm(j, mean = 500, sd = 100))
  }
}

print(Sys.time())
sim_results2 <- matrix(0, nrow = n_repetition, ncol = max_n)
set.seed(42)
for(i in 1:n_repetition){
    sim_results2[i, ] <- cummean(rnorm(max_n, mean = 500, sd = 100))

}
print(Sys.time())
```

Comment: This is really great. I have just tried it in my full simulation, and it has reduced the time of one sweep considerably. Thank you.